# How can I select all rows from one table, calculating a field value based on another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table `merchandises` and `merchandise_groups_merchandise`. The latter table is the middle table for storing which merchandise is selected inside which merchandise groups - a many to many. There's a relation from `merchandises.id` to `merchandise_groups_merchandise.merchandise_id`.

I'm trying to put together a query to produce the following results, listing all the merchandise from the `merchandises` table and where `is_selected` is a boolean decided by whether the merchandise_id is in the `merchandise_groups_merchandise` table for a specific merchandise_group. And, the `merchandise_groups_merchandise.group_id` is specified by the user.

I've tried a LEFT join, between the two tables, but of course, that only returns the actual merchandise that's in the group middle table.

How can I do this?

```
-------------------------------
|id  |title  |is_selected
---------------------------
|1   |Tree   |1
|2   |Log    |0
|3   |Toy    |1
```

This is the SQL of the query that I've tried:

```
PARAMETERS group_id Short;
SELECT IIf(IsNull([merchandise_groups_merchandise].[merchandise_id]),False,True) AS selected, merchandises.id, merchandises.title
FROM merchandises LEFT JOIN merchandise_groups_merchandise ON merchandises.id = merchandise_groups_merchandise.merchandise_id
WHERE (((merchandise_groups_merchandise.merchandise_group_id)=[group_id]));
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  Your explanation is a bit hard to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is with `iif()` and an `exists` subquery:

```
select m.*,
       iif(exists (select 1
                   from merchandise_groups_merchandise as mgm
                   where m.id = mgm.merchandise_id and
                         mgm.merchandise_group_id = [group_id]
                  )), 1, 0) as IsInGroupFlag
from merchandizes as m
```

Comment: My previous attempts with subqueries failed, so I assumed that Access couldn't handle them. Thankfully, it can! And the unnecessary join was throwing me off too.